# Chain is locking up

Tags: chain, drivetrain

This only happens in my granny gear going up hill, just started too. I am pedaling up a steep hill and the pedals suddenly stop, obviously the chain is jamming somehow. The first time it did this I was thrown over the handlebars. By the time I stopped to look the chain had unjammed but once I did see the rear derailleur stuck forward up near my chainstay. Not sure what is causing this. I rarely use my granny gear ever. Cassette and chain are newish.

Comment: Just a thought: are you using the granny gear and the large chain ring (i.e., your largest cogs at the front and back) simultaneously? If so, could it be that your chain isn't really long enough for that, so the rear derailleur is getting pulled almost horizontal?

Comment: Were there any unusual noises coming from the front derailleur (or elsewhere) before it happened? If your FD is badly adjusted it's possible for the chain to try to engage two chainrings at once, though this is more common during shifting

Answer (score 7):

Chain suck is the likely culprit. When the chain is dirty, lacks lube, or is otherwise out of spec (i.e., worn) is combined with a small chain ring with an off-angle chain line there can be a slight delay in disengagement of the chain from the small chain ring (the small diameter exacerbates this problem further). This delay when combined with tight tolerances between the frame and the chairring can lead to to the chain getting jammed between the frame and chainring.  This would also pull the bottom of the derailleur cage (that holds the jockey wheels) towards the front of the bike.

This was typically a problem with bikes that had triple crankset. To move to 2x and 1x has made this largely an issue of the past.

Comment: Chain suck totally, but triples would not be related in my experience.   A clean of the chain would be the first thing.

Comment: @Criggie - First step would be to examine for obvious signs of chain or sprocket wear.

Comment: @Criggie triples can have more extreme chain angles, which could contribute to the chain suck phenomenon

Comment: @DanielRHicks I think the first place to check would be the frame for signs of damage on the drive side chain stay. Freshly chipped paint would indicate a recent chain suck event.

Comment: @Rider_X - But what caused the chain to jump off and get stuck?  Chain/sprocket wear is the biggest cause of "chain suck" and related issues.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I agree, but we have haven't confirmed that chain suck is even happening (seems likely though).

Comment: This sounds exactly like chain suck on the chainring, caused by a worn chainring.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same annoying problem with my 3x9 speeds. After many incidents, I was able to observe the mechanics of it when I stopped. The chain was wrapping around the front sprocket: instead of the usual 12 to 6 o'clock chain contact, it was 12 to 10 o'clock. Chain stretch was within acceptable range. I placed the blame on the front sprocket, which was rusty. Used a wire brush to remove the rust and possible burrs. No problems since.